# jquery.dataTables search utf-8 the same characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

`DataTable Search` is not working.

I have `İNSAAT` string. When i search for `insaat`. No data is returned.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You should use `ToUpper or ToLower (in your framework)` in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a snippet of the code?
Which framework are you using?
Considering that you are using the framework from (datatables.net), use the following code to set insensitivy case search.

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
   "search": {
   "caseInsensitive": true
   }
});
```

Comment: not work, I guess İ=i not have in datatables. Impossible?